# I have Debian on my server. Should I use Centos or Ubuntu version of software I need to install?

Tags: debian

This is my server:

```
/usr/local/bin$ uname -a
Linux nn15 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The software I need is offered in these versions:

- centos-5.3.run
- centos-5.6.run
- centos-6.3.run
- ubuntu-8.04.run
- ubuntu-10.04.run
- ubuntu-12.04.run

Which one is the closest to Debian? I'm asking because I want to know which one is the most likely to work when I download and install it.

Comment: Perlnika, you do not have to delete your questions on other sites.  Doing so may trigger autoprotection systems which will block you from making posts on those other sites for some time (which is the case with this question, they initially asked it on Ask Ubuntu).  Having said this, the [tag:ubuntu] and [tag:centos] tags aren't really necessary here because the question is neither about Ubuntu nor CentOS.

Comment: This question is unclear. What software do you need? Also, it doesn't seem this question has anything to do with Debian. As far as which distribution you use, that's really up to you.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I can provide further clarification, the user is using `$some_software` but there's no Debian packages, only `.run` files.  Only those CentOS and Ubuntu `.run` files are available, and they want to know which they should use.  I do agree it's unclear though, if they said which software it was, it could maybe be more answerable.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. That is helpful, though I don't know what `.run` files are. Google links don't tell me either.

Comment: @FaheemMitha a `.run` is just a binary installer, really.  I know this isn't on U&L, but [maybe this can help explain what a `.run` file is](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13415/what-are-run-files)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of the list, Ubuntu 12.04 is likely to be closest to Debian wheezy.  However, there is no guarantee that your package will work at all on Debian.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that the Ubuntu package is compatible with Debian, that would be the safer bet, as Debian and Ubuntu both use `.deb` package management, while CentOS uses Red Hat's `.rpm` packages.

Comment: Lets be careful throwing "package" around, it appears the software providers don't have `.deb` or `.rpm` packages, and rather binary installers that don't work with standard packaging systems.